# Check that a string starts with a drive letter in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm writing a script that will take a list of file paths as input.  I want the script to make sure the strings in the input file are, or at least appear to be, valid full Windows paths, that include the drive letter.

That being said, what's the best way to ensure that a string starts with any single letter, upper or lowercase, a colon, and a back slash?

I'm guessing the regex would look something like this:

[a-zA-Z]:\, but how do I make sure it check for only one letter and that it's the first 3 characters in the string?

I appreciate it.

Comment: Put a caret (^) in front of your regex, like ^[a-zA-Z]:\

Comment: Couldn't you just check if path is real (rather than appears to be real) by calling ```os.path.exists()```?

Comment: @wnnmaw, unfortunately no, because these are going to be paths are remote computers.  Eventually I'm going to be calling PSEXEC to run a program on a remote computer using the paths in the input file.  I at least want to make sure the paths are full paths before I try to pass them to PSEXEC.

Comment: You could use `os.path.splitdrive()` and see of if the `drive` value returned is empty or not.

Answer (score 6):

The `^` character matches the start of the string. Your character class will currently only match one letter, and you need to escape the `\`. So your final regex would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z]:\\
```

Comment: That worked, I just had to add an asterisk to the end.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z]:\\ is working in javascript too :)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check to make sure it starts with a drive letter, you could also use the built-in `splitdrive`:

```
drive, path = os.path.splitdrive(filename)
if drive == None:
    raise ValueError, 'Filename does not include a drive!'
```

Edit: Thanks to jme, if you are not on a Windows system, do `import ntpath` and replace the first line like this:

```
drive, path = ntpath.splitdrive(filename)
```

Note: since Python 2.7.8, splitdrive returns a 'drive' for UNC paths too.

Comment: This is arguably the correct way to do this, but if the script is not running on windows, he'll need to `import ntpath` instead of `import os`. Otherwise `splitdrive` will produce a tuple where the first entry is always the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Checks that the given path is a valid windows path based on criteria at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I made this a little while ago out of frustration of not finding a good one online:

```
r'^(?:[a-zA-Z]:\\|\\\\?|\\\\\?\\|\\\\\.\\)?(?:(?!(CLOCK\$(\\|$)|(CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9]| )(?:\..*|(\\|$))|.*\.$))(?:(?:(?![><:/"\\\|\?\*])[\x20-\u10FFFF])+\\?))*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what ended up working for me.

```
is_path = re.match("^[a-zA-Z]:\\)*", file)
```